# AngularJS Service Undefined: Unknown provider: $scopeProvider <- $scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've started learning Angular JS and I'm having a problem with injecting a service into a controller. I'm trying to put the `ThreadFactory` service into `ThreadController`, but I'm getting an undefined error when calling it. Any advice would be great. The error I'm getting is:

Unknown provider: $scopeProvider <- $scope <- ThreadService

**app.js**

```
angular.module('threadsApp', ['ngRoute']);
angular.module('threadsApp')
    .config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/', {
                templateUrl: 'views/index.html',
            })
            .when('/selected/:topicName', {
                templateUrl: 'views/threads.html',
                controller: 'ThreadController',
            })
            .otherwise({
                redirectTo: "/"
            });
            $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    });
```

**ThreadController.js**

```
angular.module('threadsApp').controller("ThreadController",
    ["$scope", "$route", "$routeParams", "ThreadService", function ($scope, $route, $routeParams, ThreadService) {
    $scope.test = "Hello!";
    $scope.test2 = ThreadService.get();
}]);
```

**ThreadService.js**

```
angular.module('threadsApp').service("ThreadService", ["$scope", function ($scope) {
    return {
        get: function() {
            return "Hello";
        }
    }
}]);
```

**Order of Imports**

```
    <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="components/app.js"></script>
    <script src="components/bodyController.js"></script>
    <script src="components/TopicController.js"></script>
    <script src="components/ThreadService.js"></script>
    <script src="components/ThreadController.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can't actually inject `$scope` into your `ThreadService` the way you're trying to.  `$scope` isn't a typical service when you inject it into a controller.  If you remove the `$scope` injection from *Threadservice.js*, I would bet the error will go away.

In the interest of not being redundant, a fuller explanation can be found here:

[Injecting $scope into an angular service function()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22898927/injecting-scope-into-an-angular-service-function)