# Factory is not getting injected into the controller - angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection

I am new to angularJS. I am trying to seperate service into a seperate file in my application.
Everything works fine, but when i try to inject the factory object to the controller it is not working. Below is the code

here is the app file
app.js

```
'use strict';

var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);  
app.config(function ($routeProvider, $controllerProvider,

          $compileProvider, $filterProvider, $provide) {
app.controllerProvider = $controllerProvider;
app.compileProvider = $compileProvider;
app.routeProvider = $routeProvider;
app.filterProvider = $filterProvider;
app.provide = $provide;


app.routeResolver = function (basePath, viewName,controllerName, isSecure) {
    var routeConf =
        {
            templateUrl: 'Views/' + basePath + viewName + '.html',
            controller: controllerName + 'Controller',
            secure: isSecure ? isSecure : false,
            resolve: {
                deps: function ($q, $rootScope) {
                    var deferred = $q.defer();
                    var dependencies =
                    [
                        'Controllers/' + basePath + controllerName + 'Controller.js',
                    ];

                    require(dependencies, function () {
                        $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                            deferred.resolve();
                        });
                    });

                    return deferred.promise;
                }
            }
        }
    return routeConf;

}

$routeProvider
.when('/', {})
.when('/Admin', app.routeResolver('Admin/', 'Admin','Admin'))
.when('/Customer', app.routeResolver('Customer/', 'Customer','Customer'))
.when('/Teller', app.routeResolver('Teller/', 'Teller','Teller'))
.when('/Finance', app.routeResolver('Finance/', 'Finance','Finance'))   
.otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
});
```

Here is my factory
AuthenticationService.js

```
'use strict';

app.factory('authenticationService', ['$scope', 'httpService', function ($scope,      httpService) {

return {
    authenticateUser: function () {
        if (!$scope.userName && !$scope.keyWord) {
            var result = httpService.postService(
                 {
                     username: $scope.userName,
                     keyword: $scope.keyWord
                 }, "../api/authenticateUser");
            result.then(successCall, errorCall);
        }
    }
}

successCall =function(dataObject) {

}

errorCall = function (dataObject) {

}

}]);
```

Here is my controller
LoginController.js

```
'use strict';

app.controller('LoginController', ['$scope','authenticationService',  function ($scope, authenticationService) {

$scope.ValidateLogin = function () {
    var result = window.confirm("Validate Login Called for the user :" + $scope.userName);
    var result1 = authenticationService.authenticateUser();

}
}]);
```

the logincontroller is working fine when i am not injecting the authenticationservice. But when i try to inject authenticationservice, it is not working. what am i doing worng. Your help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.
Note : I have tried creating this as a service as well. Still this is not working.

Comment: Whats the error in the console, also what version of angular

Comment: I call this method ValidateLogin on click of Login button from index.html. this is called when i dont inject authentication service. that is how i am finding it out. @license AngularJS v1.3.8

Comment: Why isn't app defined in each of the javascript files?

Comment: that is a global variable as defined in app.js. This has a value when i debug in all the files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although it's not recommended to access $scope inside your factories and services,you can using `angular.element(ELEMENT).scope()`.

But it's better to make your authentication service accept a username and password and assume nothing about its current scope to make it re-usable:

```
authenticateUser: function (username, password) {
    ...... // 
    return result.then(successCall, errorCall); // return the promise 
}
```

Then in your controller:

```
$scope.ValidateLogin = function () {
 ....//
     authenticationService.authenticateUser($scope.username, $scope.password)
         .then(function(response){
          // deal with the response here
          });

}
```

Comment: Also as pointed by @topheman you have a hoisting problem, combine both answers and you have a functional factory.

Comment: thanks for the optimization tips. I have made the changes as suggested. but to begin with,the problem i have is, the validateLogin is not getting called when i inject authenticationService.

Comment: Can you make sure that your AuthenticationService is injected in the right order in your Index.html, before the controllers js and after the app.js

Comment: Hi teleaziz... thanks for the input. Now i could see the httpservice that i used in the authenticationservice is getting initialized, but not the authenticationservice. i have the files injected in the right order as you have mentioned.

Comment: is the httpService something you defined? or is it something I missed in Angular? I usually use $http instead: `$http.post(authRoute, data)`

Comment: I have defined it... its an abstract to web api calls... inside that i use $http and $q... that factory is getting initialized...

Comment: Is that `httpService` also defined in `app` or in an other module ?

Comment: Its also defined in app module. now i got rid of it and used $http.post in the authentication service itself as mentioned by @teleaziz and everthing works fine now. Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The basic problem here is your factory is not getting initialized properly.
The factory definition is incorrect because you are using `$scope`.
`$scope` is not a service and but an object. `$scope`object is bound to some html elements/context. We can use `$scope` with controllers as Injector initializes controllers with `$scope` while parsing the html elements. Controllers are associated with html elements and hence Injector knows the `$scope` for the controller.
But services/factories are singleton objects. So you cannot inject `$scope` here.

For additional clarifications, you may refer 
[Injecting $scope into an angular service function()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22898927/injecting-scope-into-an-angular-service-function)

using following code would resolve your issue. I assume you have already defined `httpsService`.

```
app.factory('authenticationService', ['httpService', function (httpService) {

return {
    authenticateUser: function (context) {
        if (!context.userName && !context.keyWord) {
            var result = httpService.postService(
                 {
                     username: context.userName,
                     keyword: context.keyWord
                 }, "../api/authenticateUser");
            result.then(successCall, errorCall);
        }
    }
}

app.controller('LoginController', ['$scope','authenticationService',  function ($scope, authenticationService) {

$scope.ValidateLogin = function () {
    var result = window.confirm("Validate Login Called for the user :" + $scope.userName);
    var result1 = authenticationService.authenticateUser($scope);

}
}]);
```

Answer (score -1):

You have a hoisting problem in your service :

```
'use strict';

app.factory('authenticationService', ['$scope', 'httpService', function ($scope,      httpService) {

//define them here before the return, if not, they won't be defined
var successCall =function(dataObject) {

}

var errorCall = function (dataObject) {

}

return {
    authenticateUser: function () {
        if (!$scope.userName && !$scope.keyWord) {
            var result = httpService.postService(
                 {
                     username: $scope.userName,
                     keyword: $scope.keyWord
                 }, "../api/authenticateUser");
            result.then(successCall, errorCall);
        }
    }
}

}]);
```