# Unable to access $http response data in Angular JS factory

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-service

I am trying to save `$http` response data in a variable inside angularJS factory. But I could not access the response outside the http method. It is showing `undefined`. I checked this link  [Injecting $scope into an angular service function()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22898927/injecting-scope-into-an-angular-service-function) Please let me know how to handle this.
Below is the factory code:

```js
angular.module('myapp')
  .factory('CardNumberFactory',['$http', function ($http) {
    // Service logic
    var details={};
  
    $http.get('scripts/services/mock.json')
      .then(function(responce){       
        var resopnceData = responce.data;
            details=resopnceData;
      });

    console.log(details);
    return {details:details};
}]);
```

Comment: At the time that you are logging the variable, it is still `undefined`. It only becomes defined inside `.then`, which happens asynchronously some time later.

Comment: http://andyshora.com/promises-angularjs-explained-as-cartoon.html

Comment: `return $http.get(..)` instead - this returns a promise - and `.then` it in the controller and assign the return value to your `$scope`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the $http service is asynchrony. You should do this like that:

```
angular.module('myapp')
  .factory('CardNumberFactory',['$http', function ($http) {

    var details={};

    function getData() {
      return $http.get('scripts/services/mock.json')
       .then(function(response){
         return {details: response.data}
      });      
    }

    return {

        getData: getData

     }

}]);

angular.module('myapp').controller('TestController, function($scope,CardNumberFactory) {

  CardNumberFactory.getData().then(function(res) {
      //  res is the {details} object
  })

})
```

Comment: I followed the same way and superb it is working! But i am trying to save the response data in separate global variable to share the data with another controller. How can i do this?

Comment: You can inject the factory to any controller that you want and call this function and grab the data or you can make a constant and save the data there, there is many ways.