# Unknown provider error when trying to dependency inject a service to a controller in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection, angularjs-service, angularjs-controller

I'm new at Angular and trying to do a basic dependency injection to get the hang of it. In this example I'm trying to dependency inject a service to a controller, and I'm getting the following error.

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $scopeProvider <- $scope <- testInjection
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/7EunSFUXEA91zPFA0iKh)

Html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0-rc.1/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.0-rc.1"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>
  </body>

</html>
```

js:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', ['testInjection',function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
}]).factory('testInjection', ['$scope', function($scope) {

  }]);
```

Comment: The `$scope` can *ONLY* be injected in controllers (standalone or in directives). Your service must use something else (and I would even consider if using a view construct, like the scope, in a service is sane anyway).

Comment: You’d better have a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22898927/injecting-scope-into-an-angular-service-function

Answer (score 0):

You should do this :

```
app.factory('testInjection', ['$scope', function($scope) {

 }]);

app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', 'testInjection',function($scope, testInjection) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
}]);
```

It's better to define your service (factory) before.
And the problem here is that even if the scope is injected in the service, you have to inject it again in the controller.

Comment: why is it better to declare the factory before? 
also, it actually does not make sense to inject `$scope` into a service..

Comment: I agree with the fact that it doesn't make sens to inject scope, because a service should be context less... For the service before the controller, it is just a convention that i use because controller use it so it should be define before even if in that case it will work anyway.

Answer (score 0):

As Nikos said, don't try to inject the scope object into a service or factory.

For my angular projects, I create a new file for each controller/service/factory/directive. The setup of these files look like this:

A factory:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('MyModule')
           .factory('someService', function () {
               var service = {
                   myFunction: function () { 
                       return "Hello";
                   }
               };

               return service;
           });
})();
```

A controller:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('MyModule')
           .controller('someCtrl', ['$scope', 'someService', function ($scope, someService) {
               $scope.name = "World";
               $scope.message = someService.myFunction() + " " + $scope.name;
           }]);
})();
```

Beware, the above syntax only retrieves a existing module. See [Angular Modules](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module) under "Creation versus Retrieval". I have another file which creates the module using the same syntax but with brackets for importing other modules.

You should take a look at the [angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api) for more information and examples.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, as I said I'm new so it might take me a while to select the best answer. Using your technique do you put each controller/service/factory/directive in it's own module, and then inject dependencies module to module?

Comment: No, it's using the same module with the name "MyModule". You could divide your code into multiple modules and inject these into other modules, but I think that's a bit advanced for this example.

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/HSpe2pd7ST6Yj91ZBRA5?p=preview). Please check the way you define a service and the way you inject it. It does not matter even if you define it after the controller. Also, the error was because your factory function did not return anything. Fixed that as well.

Your code should look like:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl'['$scope','testInjection',function($scope,testInjectio)
 {
  $scope.name = testInjection;
}]).factory('testInjection', function() {
       return "ABC"
  });
```