# AngularJs show Error: [$injector:modulerr] in console?

Tags: angularjs, ngresource, ngroute

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="adaniapp">
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="main">
        <div ng-view></div>
    </div>
  <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/angular-route.js"></script>
  <script src="js/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

**Javascript**

```
var adaniapp = angular.module('adaniapp', ['ngRoute','ngResource']);
// configure our routes
adaniapp.config(['$scope', '$routeProvider', '$resource',function($scope, $routeProvider, $resource) {
    $routeProvider

        // route for the home page
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl : 'page/login.html',
            controller  : 'mainController'
        })

        // route for the about page
        .when('/home', {
            templateUrl : 'page/home.html',
            controller  : 'HomeController'
        })

        // route for the contact page
        .when('/meter', {
            templateUrl : 'page/meter.html',
            controller  : 'MeterController'
        })

        .when('/viewbill', {
            templateUrl : 'page/viewbill.html',
            controller  : 'ViewbillController'
        });
}]);

// create the controller and inject Angular's $scope
adaniapp.controller('mainController',['$scope', '$routeProvider', '$resource', function($scope, $routeProvider, $resource) {

}]);

adaniapp.controller('HomeController',['$scope', '$routeProvider', '$resource', function($scope, $routeProvider, $resource) {

}]);

adaniapp.controller('MeterController',['$scope', '$routeProvider', '$resource', function($scope, $routeProvider, $resource) {

}]);

adaniapp.controller('MeterController',['$scope', '$routeProvider', '$resource', function($scope, $routeProvider, $resource) {

}]);
```

included ng-resource.js file and route.js file are included in index.html, but still its showing error in my console as

> "Error: [$injector:modulerr]
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.15/$injector/modulerr?p0="

all controller included.

Comment: include jquery before angular.js file... Bcoz angular.js uses jquery...

Comment: @GnanaduraiA this is not true

Comment: @GnanaduraiA There is absolutely no need of including Jquery and angular doesn't use Jquery, it's JQLite

Comment: @Augustian first of all, please, have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22898927/injecting-scope-into-an-angular-service-function.

Comment: Why do you have two controllers named `MeterController`? It's a copy-and-paste-but-forgot-to-change-name mistake right?

Comment: Why are you adding $scope and $resource to config when it's not being needed?

Comment: Even i change the controller also.. but still it not working . showing same error in console.

Comment: I removed   $scope and $resource in $config, but still its showing same error in console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can't inject `$scope` during configuration phase.

> **Configuration blocks** - get executed during the provider registrations and configuration phase. Only **providers** and **constants** can be injected into configuration blocks. This is to prevent accidental instantiation of services before they have been fully configured.

2. You can't inject `$routeProvider` in controllers since it is already configured, use `$route` service instead.

Comment: Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.15/$injecto erroring getting now

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you're actually missing some scripts. Try bower installing them or add them manually if not using bower. Missing `angular-route.js`, which is not included with angular, is especially common. If there are any 404's in your web developer console, they would help confirm that suspicion (although there's a small chance your web server might not be serving them as 404's if it's configured in an unusual way).