# Angular error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: lineChartProvider <- lineChart <- MainController

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular-services

Not Sure why but my controller wont recognize the service. I have checked enerything what am I missing here. I have included the services file in HTML. It recognizes other services but not just this one

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('pollyvotes')
    .service('lineChart', lineChart);

    /** @ngInject */
    function lineChart($scope, $http){
      var promise = null;
      return function(){
        if (promise){
          return promise
        } else {
          promise = $http.jsonp('')
          .success(function(data){
            $scope.predictions = data;
         })
          .error( function(data){
            $scope.data = "Request failed";
          })

          return promise;
        }

      }
```

Controller

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('pollyvotes')
    .controller('MainController', MainController);

  /** @ngInject */
  function MainController($scope, $timeout, lineChart) {

    $scope.photos = [   {id: 'chart-1', name: 'something here',src: "assets/images/300x600.png", href: "https://www.google.de/?gws_rd=ssl", discription: "say something about the chart here"},
                        {id: 'chart-2', name: 'another picture', src: "assets/images/300x600.png", href: "https://www.google.de/?gws_rd=ssl", discription: "say something about the chart here"},
                        {id: 'chart-3', name: 'another picture', src: "assets/images/300x600.png", href: "https://www.google.de/?gws_rd=ssl", discription: "say something about the chart here"},
                        {id: 'chart-4', name: 'another picture', src: "assets/images/300x600.png", href: "https://www.google.de/?gws_rd=ssl", discription: "say something about the chart here"}
                    ];

  }

})();
```

and declaring module

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('pollyvotes', ['ngAnimate', 'ngCookies', 'ngTouch', 'ngSanitize',
                           'ngMessages', 'ngAria', 'ngResource', 'ui.router',
                           'ui.bootstrap',  'akoenig.deckgrid', 'smoothScroll',
                           'ngToast', 'picardy.fontawesome']);

})();
```

Comment: just to be clear, did you declare the 'pollyvotes' module somewhere else ?

I mean do you have somewhere

```javascript
angular.module('pollyvotes', []);
```

to define the module.

Comment: yes I do,  adding it up with the code as well

Comment: I assume you forgot that bit in the question `})();` and it exists in your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are injecting $scope to your service.

That's what the documentation says about this error:
https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr

> Attempting to inject a scope object into anything that's not a controller or 
>       a directive, for example a service, will also throw an 
>       Unknown provider:     $scopeProvider <- $scope error.

There is a good answer how to avoid this here:
[Injecting $scope into an angular service function()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22898927/injecting-scope-into-an-angular-service-function)