# $scope is not defined in service AngularJs:

Tags: javascript, angularjs

> got error of scope not defined when i use for response message:

```
$scope.responsemessage = response;
```

> then I added $scope here like this:

```
app.service('fileUpload', ['$http', '$scope', function ($http, $scope) {
```

> When I added above $scope got this error Error: [$injector:unpr]
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.8/$injector/unpr?p0=.................

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22898927/injecting-scope-into-an-angular-service-function

$scope” is an object instance of a controller. “$scope” object instance get’s created when “ng-controller” directive is encountered.

Comment: may be try $rootScope if you want, that will visible in service too

Comment: this are not working. Just simply i want to show response message on success in views

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Service don't have scope.

If you wanna to use scope inside service , have to pass it from controller .

Like this

In controller

```
fileUpload.checkFile($scope.responsemessage);
```

In service

```
function checkFile(respMsg)
{
   console.log(respMsg);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`$scope`s are not available from services, it should only be used inside controllers.

Comment: this are not working. Just simply i want to show response message on success in views

Answer (score 1):

In angular `$scope` is available in controllers and services are used as a dependency for data provider.

You just can't use `$scope` in the service and from service you can return a promise object like:

```
app.service('fileUpload', ['$http', function($http) {
    return $http.post('url')
}]);
```

Now you can inject this service to update a variable on the controller's `$scope`:

```
app.controller('cntrl', ['$scope', 'fileUpload',  function($scope, fileUpload){
      $scope.responsemessage = fileUpload.then(function(data){
          return data;
      })
}]);
```

Comment: this are not working. Just simply i want to show response message on success in views

Answer (score 0):

You can not use $scope in Services as well as in Factories.
You can call service by giving $scope value as a parameter and save the return value to the $scope variable

Comment: this are not working. Just simply i want to show response message on success in views