# Why are Callbacks from Promise `.then` Methods an Anti-Pattern

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise, anti-patterns

I have seen answers on StackOverflow where people suggest furnishing a callback function to an AngularJS service.

```
app.controller('tokenCtrl', function($scope, tokenService) {
    tokenService.getTokens(function callbackFn(tokens) {
        $scope.tokens = tokens;
    });
});

app.factory('tokenService', function($http) {
    var getTokens = function(callbackFn) {
        $http.get('/api/tokens').then (function onFulfilled(response) {
            callbackFn(response.data);
        });
    };

    return {
        getTokens: getTokens
    };
});
```

This seems to me to be an Anti-Pattern. The `$http` service returns promises and having `.then` methods execute callback functions feels like an unhealthy inversion of control.

How does one **re-factor** code like this and how does one explain why the original way was **not a good idea?**

Comment: Just tell people to actually use promises instead of ignoring them.

Comment: I found using `promise` is kind of healthy, as it has ability to chain it and have control over async call.

Comment: Main issue is that with nothing returned in `then()` there is nowhere to catch errors in callback. It breaks the promise chain

Comment: using the promise makes the code shorter and simpler too.

Comment: this service returning an object doesn't make much sense... it needs to return a promise so that whatever uses it can know when the data is ready.

Comment: "these callbacks from a promise are a **big** anti-pattern — *architects hate them!*"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code can be re-factored as follows:

```
app.controller('tokenCtrl', function($scope, tokenService) {
    tokenService.getTokens.then ( callbackFn(tokens) {
        $scope.tokens = tokens;
    });
});

app.factory('tokenService', function($http) {
    var getTokens = function() {
        //return promise
        return $http.get('/api/tokens').then (function onFulfilled(response) {
                //return tokens
                return response.data;
            }
        );
    };

    return {
        getTokens: getTokens
    };
});
```

By having the service return a promise, and using the `.then` method of the promise, the same functionality is achieved with the following benefits:

- The promise can be saved and used for **chaining**.
- The promise can be saved and used to avoid repeating the same `$http` call.
- Error information is retained and can be retrieved with the `.catch` method.
- The promise can be forwarded to other clients.

Answer (score 8):

You should change it to

```
var getTokens = function() {
      return $http.get('/api/tokens');
    };
```

And, then in other module use

```
yourModule.getTokens()
  .then(function(response) {
    // handle it
  });
```

As to why it's an anti-pattern, I'd say that, first,  it doesn't allow you to further chain your success/fail handler methods. Second, it handles the control of processing the response from caller-module to called module (which might not be super-important here, but it still imposes same inversion of control). And finally, you add the concept of promises to your codebase, which might not be so easy to understand for some of the teammates, but then use promises as callbacks, so this really makes no sense.