# Sending data to factory from controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router, angular-services

my factory is:

```
 myAppServices.factory('ProfileData',['$http',  function($http){
            return{
            newly_joined:function(callback){
            $http.get(
//myUrl will be an url from controller.
                myUrl
            ).success(callback);
              }
    };

          }
                                            ]);
```

and I have three controller which has different URL:

controller1:

```
AppControllers.controller('ProfileListCtrl',['$scope','$state', '$rootScope', 'ProfileData', '$timeout',   function($scope, $state, $rootScope, ProfileData, $timeout ) {


    ProfileData.newly_joined(function(response) {
      var myUrl= "www.abc...." 
     //something goes there
});

     }]);
```

controller2:

```
AppControllers.controller('ProfileListCtrl1',['$scope','$state', '$rootScope', 'ProfileData', '$timeout',   function($scope, $state, $rootScope, ProfileData, $timeout ) {


    ProfileData.newly_joined(function(response) {
      var myUrl= "www.abc...." 
     //something goes there
});

     }]);
```

and controller 3 is:

```
AppControllers.controller('ProfileListCtrl2',['$scope','$state', '$rootScope', 'ProfileData', '$timeout',   function($scope, $state, $rootScope, ProfileData, $timeout ) {


    ProfileData.newly_joined(function(response) {
      var myUrl= "www.abc...." 
     //something goes there
});

     }]);
```

I want different data in different controller because of different URL and I am showing all three details on single web page.

So if there were any method to send *'myUrl'* in factory that I can use that for pulling data.

Note: please don't suggest me for using $resource or $routeparams because $resource was not successfull in pulling data from json and I don't want to use big variable Url for my page.

Thanks in advance

Comment: So depending on the controller you want different data returned? If that's the case, why not create 3 separate methods (I think that's the best design), or just pass a name to `newly_joined` like `newly_joined("profile")` vs. `newly_joined("profile1")` (not as good of a solution)?

Comment: I should also mention that the `success` callback on `$http` is deprecated, see https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http. You should be using `then` instead.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is add an additional parameter to the newly_joined function:

```
newly_joined:function(callback, myUrl){
```

Also, you should be using .then instead of .success

Comment: Hi @austin can u create a plunker example for it . If yes then it will be great.

Answer (score 0):

Your factory should be returning promises instead of using callbacks.

```
myAppServices.factory('ProfileData',['$http',  function($http){
    return function(myUrl) {
        return $http.get(myUrl);
    };
}]);
```

The controller

```
AppControllers.controller('ProfileListCtrl',['$scope', 'ProfileData', function($scope,ProfileData) {

    var myUrl= "www.abc....";
    var httpPromise = ProfileData(myUrl);

    httpPromise.then(function onFulfilled(response) {
        $scope.data = response.data;
    }).catch(function onRejected(response) {
        console.log("ERROR ", response.status);
    });

}]);
```

The [DEMO on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v93sujtr/)

The advantage of using promises is that they retain error information.

Also notice that `myUrl` is sent to the factory as an argument.

For more information on the advantages of using promises, see [Why are Callbacks from Promise Then Methods an Anti-Pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35660881/why-are-callbacks-from-promise-then-methods-an-anti-pattern)

Comment: hi @georgeawg, can u create a plunker here because I am getting error as following:
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.4/$injector/undef?p0=ProfileData

Comment: u can use this json file as a sample:
http://www.w3schools.com/website/customers_mysql.php