# Assigning variable from a factory to a control doesn't work

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise, angular-services, angular-http

My html is this:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl as ctrl" class="bodyContainer">
<div ng-repeat="stuff in ctrl.stuffies">
    here
</div>
```

This is my controller:

```
angular.module("AuthenticationApp", ["BaseApp"])
    .controller("MainCtrl", ["$http", "$window", "BaseService", function($http, $window, BaseService) {
        var self = this;

        BaseService.fetch.stuffs(function() {
            self.stuffies = BaseService.stuffies;
            console.log(self.stuffies);
            self.cerrorMessages = BaseService.cerrorMessages;
        });
    }]);
```

And this is my `BaseApp`:

```
angular.module("BaseApp", [])
    .config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
        $httpProvider.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'csrftoken';
        $httpProvider.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = 'X-CSRFToken';
    }])

    .config(['$locationProvider', function($locationProvider){
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    }])

    .factory("BaseService", ["$http", "$window", function($http, $window) {
        var self = this;


        /* All functions which call fetch should have a callback function
         * on the front-end which sets 
         * 1) a variable (i.e. stuffies etc.)
         * 2) and BaseService.cerrorMessages. */
        self.fetch = {
             stuff: function(callback) {
                 $http.get("/stuffs/")
                 .then(function(response) {
                     self.stuffies = response.data;
                     callback();
                 }, function(response) {
                     self.accessErrors(response.data);
                     callback();
                 });
             }
        };
```

The problem is, even though it logs an item inside `self.stuffies` (when this line is run: `console.log(self.stuffies);`), `here` is not printed in the HTML. There doesn't seem to be anything inside `ctrl.stuffies`. I tried moving `console.log(self.stuffies);` outside of `BaseService.fetch.stuffs(function()` and it logs `undefined`. How do I get `ctrl.stuffies` to be `BaseService.stuffies`?

Comment: Read [Why are Callbacks from Promise `.then` Methods an Anti-Pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35660881/why-are-callbacks-from-promise-then-methods-an-anti-pattern).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to use callbacks with the $http service as it returns promises:

```
//.factory("BaseService", ["$http", "$window", function($http, $window) {
app.service("BaseService", ["$http", "$window", function($http, $window) {
    //var self = this;


    /* All functions which call fetch should have a callback function
     * on the front-end which sets 
     * 1) a variable (i.e. stuffies etc.)
     * 2) and BaseService.cerrorMessages. */
    this.fetch = {
         stuff: function() {
           //vvvv RETURN the promise
           return $http.get("/stuffs/")
             .then(function(response) {
                 //vvvv RETURN the data
                 return response.data;
                 //self.stuffies = response.data;
                 //callback();
           });//, function(response) {
             //    self.accessErrors(response.data);
             //    callback();
             //});
         }
    };
});
```

There is no need to do anything with $http errors in the service. Errors will be carried forward automatically in the promise.

Then in the controller extract the data (or the error) from the promise:

```
/* REPLACE
BaseService.fetch.stuffs(function() {
    self.stuffies = BaseService.stuffies;
    console.log(self.stuffies);
    self.cerrorMessages = BaseService.cerrorMessages;
});
*/


BaseService.fetch.stuffs
  .then(function(data) {
    self.stuffies = data;
    console.log(self.stuffies);
}).catch(function(errorResponse) {
    self.cerrorMessages = errorResponse.data;
});
```

For more information, see

- [AngularJS $http Service API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http).
- [MDN JavaScript Reference - `return` Statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return)

---

> I changed your service to a factory <del>and made it this:</del> *and used it this way:*
>
> ```
> BaseService.fetch.stuffs() 
>   .then(function(data) {
>     self.stuffs = data;
>     console.log(self.stuffs);  
> }).catch(function(errorResponse) { 
>     self.cerrorMessages = errorResponse.data; 
> });
> ```
>
> Is this fine (using factory because there are other functions inside the factory as well and I don't want to have to change them all to services)?
>
> ---
>
> Sorry, the factory is
>
> ```
> self.fetch = { 
>     stuffs: function() { 
>         return $http.get("/stuffs/")
>           .then(function(response) {
>               return response.data; 
>         });
>     }
> };
> ```

Either a service or a factory will work. With a service, functions can be added by adding properties to the `this` context which is automatically returned (unless overridden with a `return` statement). With a factory, a `return` statement is manditory. Functions are added to the object returned. The choice is a question of style. They are both used the same way.

Comment: I changed your service to a factory and made it this: `BaseService.fetch.stuffs()
          .then(function(data) {
            self.stuffs = data;
            console.log(self.stuffs);
        }).catch(function(errorResponse) {
            self.cerrorMessages = errorResponse.data;
        });` Is this fine (using factory because there are other functions inside the factory as well and I don't want to have to change them all to services)?

Comment: Sorry, the factory is `self.fetch = {
         stuffs: function() {
           return $http.get("/stuffs/")
             .then(function(response) {
                 return response.data;
           });
         }
        };` And the controller is what I posted in the comment above.

Comment: Would you be able to look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43130404/how-to-correctly-override-errresponse-which-is-passed-to-the-catchfunctione and say how to fix the code without using a callback? (I know how to do it with a callback, but since you mentioned it is an Anti-Pattern, I just wanted to see your opinion)

Answer (score 1):

You're using a factory like a service.

Have your factory self call (initialize) its `self.fetch` function, then upon construction of your controller, set the controller's `stuffies` variable equal to the factory's `stuffies` variable.

**Edit:**

If you only want some of the data initialized at once, you can self call only the functions you want to retrieve data initially.

You can then use a resolve in your routing to initialize more data when a specific route is hit.

Comment: But I only want the factory to fetch `stuffies` when it is needed (when a controller / `HTML` page asks for it). There are other variables (`stuffies2`, `stuffies3`, `stuffies4` etc.) which all need to be fetched as well for different `HTML` pages so I don't want my factory to fetch them all at the start (would only want them to be fetched when the `HTML` page which needs it is loaded).

Comment: Try resolving the factory method as a promise when the route changes to the route with your controller/template: http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/05/20/using-resolve-in-angularjs-routes.aspx