# How to correctly override `errResponse` which is passed to the `catch(function(errResponse){` function?

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise, angular-services, angular-http

This is my controller:

```
angular.module("AuthenticationApp", ["BaseApp"])
    .controller("MainCtrl", ["$http", "$window", "BaseService", function($http, $window, BaseService) {
        var self = this;

        self.add = function() {
            BaseService.add.user(self.user)
                .catch(function(errorResponse) {
                    self.cerrorMessages = errorResponse.data;
                });
        };
```

This is my `BaseApp` / factory:

```
angular.module("BaseApp", [])
    .config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
        $httpProvider.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'csrftoken';
        $httpProvider.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = 'X-CSRFToken';
    }])

    .factory("BaseService", ["$http", "$window", function($http, $window) {
        var self = this;

        self.add = {
            user: function(user) {
                $http.post("/users/", user)
                .then(function(response) {
                    $http.post("/api-auth/login", user)
                    .then(function(response) {
                        $window.location.href = "/";
                    });
                // if there are errors, rewrite the error messages
                }).catch(function(response) {
                     for (prop in response.data) {
                         if (prop == "email") {
                             response.data[prop] = "Please enter a valid email address.";
                         } else if (prop == "username") {
                             response.data[prop] = "Please enter a valid username";
                         }
                     }
                });
            }
         };
```

When I try to run this code and call `self.add()` on my controller, I get an error saying `TypeError: Cannot read property 'catch' of undefined` pointing to the line `.catch(function(errorResponse) {` in my controller. I'm guessing this is because there is no `then()` function.

What should I do to properly override the `errResponse` parameter which is passed to the controller's `.catch()` function (without having a `.then()` function because nothing is needed to be done if it is successful)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I try to run this code and call `self.add()` on my controller, I get an error saying `TypeError: Cannot read property 'catch' of 'undefined'` pointing to the line `.catch(function(errorResponse) {` in my controller. I'm guessing this is because there is no then() function.

That is an erroneous guess. The `self.add()` returned `undefined` because the function omitted a `return` statement. When functions omit `return` statements, they return the primitive value `undefined`. There is neither a `.then` method nor a `.catch` method on the primitive `undefined`. Thus the `TypeError: Cannot read property 'catch'`.

**It is important to [return](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return) the httpPromise:**

```
user: function(user) {
    //vvvv RETURN the promise
    return $http.post("/users/", user)
      .then(function successHandler(response) {
        //vvvv RETURN to chain
        return $http.post("/api-auth/login", user)
    }).then(function successHandler(response) {
        $window.location.href = "/";
    // if there are errors, rewrite the error messages
    }).catch(function rejectHandler(errorResponse) {
         for (prop in errorResponse.data) {
             if (prop == "email") {
                 errorResponse.data[prop] = "Please enter a valid email address.";
             } else if (prop == "username") {
                 errorResponse.data[prop] = "Please enter a valid username";
             }
         }
         //vvvv THROW to chain rejections
         throw errorResponse;
    });
}
```

Also **it is important to use a [throw statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/throw) in rejection handlers.** Otherwise the rejection will be **converted** to a *success*. If a rejection handler omits a throw statement, it returns a primitive value of `undefined`. This means the rejection will be converted to a *successful* promise that resolves to a value of `undefined`. It will subsequently **skip** the `.catch` method in the controller.

For more information, see [Angular execution order with `$q`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34324153/angular-execution-order-with-q/34326388#34326388).

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you don't have a solid understand of promises :) I recommend learning more about them.

When you call `BaseService.add.user`, this should return a promise. You can only use `.catch` if this is a promise. Also note that when chaining promises, you need to return a promise!

So something like this:

```
self.add = {
  user: function(user) {
    return $http.post("/users/", user)
      .then(function(response) {
        return $http.post("/api-auth/login", user)
      })
      .then(function(response) {
        $window.location.href = "/";
      })
      .catch(function(response) {
        // error stuff
      });
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The **.then()** block accepts two functions for:

1. handling a successful response
2. handling errors

You don't need a catch block. Just add the callback function in case of errors to override the response like this:

```
self.add = {
            user: function(user) {
                $http.post("/users/", user)
                .then(function(response) {
                    $http.post("/api-auth/login", user)
                    .then(function(response) {
                        $window.location.href = "/";
                    }, function errorCallback(response) {
                        for (prop in response.data) {
                         if (prop == "email") {
                             response.data[prop] = "Please enter a valid email address.";
                         } else if (prop == "username") {
                             response.data[prop] = "Please enter a valid username";
                 });                    
            }
         };
```

Comment: I'm still getting an undefined error pointing to my controllers `catch()` function. What exactly do I need to do with my controllers `catch()` function? (the original error was also pointing to my controller `catch()`, not my factory)

Comment: you need to replace the catch function with the errorCallback function as demonstrated in my answer. Just replace your add function with the one I gave.