# Passing a $scope to my factor errors

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to pass a property in my $scope to my factory.  I could console.log it find, but when I try to pass it to my factory, an error occurs.

controller:

```
    mainFactory.getHigh($scope.products[0]._id, function (bid) {
        $scope.bid1 = bid;
    });
```

factory

```
  factory.getHigh = function (id, callback) {
        $http.post('/high', id)
            .then(function (response) {
                callback(response)
            })
    }
```

error: $scope.products[0]._id is undefined

Comment: Check `$scope.products`

Comment: there isn't enough information here to adequately troubleshoot your issue.  You suggest that the property has a value when you use `console.log`, but you aren't showing that here, nor are you showing where this value is being set.  This error has nothing to do with the factory;  it is indicating that `$scope.products[0]` doesn't have an `_id` property at the time the factory is called.

Comment: See [Why are Callbacks from Promise `.then` Methods an Anti-Pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35660881/why-are-callbacks-from-promise-then-methods-an-anti-pattern).