# Controller method doesn't return value to extend controller

Tags: angularjs, ajax, controllers

I have a controller who extend another controller:

I need to recieve the result of the second controller's method to a first controller's variable

First Controller:

```
angular.module('Gestios').controller('EmpresasControllerList', function($scope, $controller ) {
    angular.extend(this, $controller('AppController', {
        $scope: $scope
    }));

    $scope.App = $scope.runApp('empresas', true);

    console.log($scope.App);
});
```

Second Controller:

```
app.controller('AppController', function ($scope, $controller, AppFactory) {
    $scope.runApp = function (AppPermalink, GetResults, Filters, Callback) {
        if(!angular.isDefined(Filters)){Filters = $scope.Filters;}

        var App = {
            Load : {
                busy: false,
                page: 1
            },
            Info: {},
            Results: []
        };

        AppFactory.Applications(AppPermalink).then(function (data) {
            App.Info = data.data[0];

            if(GetResults){
                AppFactory.Items(AppPermalink, Filters).then(function (data) {
                    App.Results = {
                        list: data.data.data,
                        count: data.data.total
                    };

                    if(typeof(Callback) == "function"){Callback(true, {results: App.Results.list, count: App.Results.count});}

                    return App;
                },function () {
                    App.Results = {
                        list: [],
                        count: 0
                    };

                    if(typeof(Callback) == "function"){Callback(false, {results: App.Results.list, count: App.Results.count});}

                    return App;
                });
            }
        },function (error) {
            swal("Algo ha ido mal", error.error, "error");
        });
    };
});




});
```

The http calls recieve data
¿Problem may be caused by asynchronous http calls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it using my callbacks :p

First Controller:

```
angular.module('Gestios').controller('EmpresasControllerList', function($scope, $controller ) {
    angular.extend(this, $controller('AppController', {
        $scope: $scope
    }));

    $scope.runApp('empresas', true, false, function(Result, App){
        if(Result){
            $scope.App = App;
        }
    });
});
```

Method of second Controller (AppController):

```
$scope.runApp = function (AppPermalink, GetResults, Filters, Callback) {
    if(!angular.isDefined(Filters)){Filters = $scope.Filters;}

    var App = {
        Load : {
            busy: false,
            page: 1
        },
        Info: {},
        Results: []
    };

    AppFactory.Applications(AppPermalink).then(function (data) {
        App.Info = data.data[0];

        if(GetResults){
            AppFactory.Items(AppPermalink, Filters).then(function (data) {
                App.Results = {
                    list: data.data.data,
                    count: data.data.total
                };

                if(typeof(Callback) == "function"){Callback(true, App);}
            },function () {
                App.Results = {
                    list: [],
                    count: 0
                };

                if(typeof(Callback) == "function"){Callback(false, App);}
            });
        }
    },function (error) {
        swal("Algo ha ido mal", error.error, "error");
    });
};
```

Comment: Some people consider creating a callback-based wrapper around a promise-based API to be anti-pattern. See [Why are Callbacks from Promise `.then` Methods an Anti-Pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35660881/why-are-callbacks-from-promise-then-methods-an-anti-pattern).