# Calling scope function in controller returns zero values

Tags: angularjs

I have this function, which I call `loadAll()` at the top.

```
function loadAll() {      
        UniversalService.GetAll()
            .then(function (a) {
                $scope.all = a;

            });
    }
```

when I use it inside my html I get correct information, but I need these values later in my controller for pagination, so I call it `// get current page of items
        $scope.items = $scope.all.slice(vm.pager.startIndex, vm.pager.endIndex + 1);`

But I dont't get any values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may call this before this promise is resolved?
Adding this in the resolved promise may be your solution.

```
function loadAll() {      
        UniversalService.GetAll()
            .then(function (a) {
                $scope.all = a;
                $scope.items = $scope.all.slice(vm.pager.startIndex, vm.pager.endIndex + 1);
            });
    }
```

Or use a callback if you wont change this function:

```
    function loadAll(callback) {      
            UniversalService.GetAll()
                .then(function (a) {
                    $scope.all = a;
                    if (callback) {
                        callback();
                    }
                });
        }
```

and call it like:

```
loadAll(function() {
    $scope.items = $scope.all.slice(vm.pager.startIndex, vm.pager.endIndex + 1);
});
```

Comment: Is it possible to solve promise in other way? I can't call ` $scope.items = $scope.all.slice(vm.pager.startIndex, vm.pager.endIndex + 1);` in loadAll() function because this line is used in another function

Comment: Yes it is possible but why not an optional callback? I edited the answer.

Comment: The callback pattern is not recommended with promises. See [Why are Callbacks from Promise `.then` Methods an Anti-Pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35660881/why-are-callbacks-from-promise-then-methods-an-anti-pattern).

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to solve promise in other way? I can't call `$scope.items = $scope.all.slice(vm.pager.startIndex, vm.pager.endIndex + 1);` in `loadAll()` function because this line is used in another function

Return a promise from `UniversalService.GetAll()`:

```
function loadAll() {      
    var promise = UniversalService.GetAll();
    promise.then(function (all) {
        $scope.all = all;
    });
    //RETURN promise
    return promise;
}
```

Then use that promise in another function:

```
var loadAllPromise = loadAll();

function another(loadAllPromise) {
    loadAllPromise.then(function(all) {
        $scope.items = all.slice(vm.pager.startIndex, vm.pager.endIndex + 1);
    });
}
```

Comment: I got error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined` do you have idea there could be the problem?

Comment: That usually means a missing [return statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return).

Comment: Or an argument is missing in a function call.