# Sync Service's Async-Response to Controller Variable

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise, angularjs-service

I am having a hard time using promises and passing information between a service and controller.

The code below functions, in that it makes the calls, I get the promises back, I perform work on them, etc. I want to pass status messages back to the controller now, but I can't figure out to return them to the controller.

How can I sync `myService`'s non-promise response with my controller variable? Or should I just be returning the `$q.all` promise back to the controller and then having the controller call the `statusService`?

Ideally, I want the controller to just "fire and forget" and wait for a status response so I can update a modal.

### Controller

```
function doWork() {
  myService.doSomeWork();

  // what I'm going for:
  // var statusMessage = myService.doSomeWork(sharedDataService.onThisThing);
}
```

### Service

```
factory.doSomeWork = function() {        
  var promises = [
    queryApi("firstApiCall"), 
    queryApi("secondApiCall")
  ];

  $q.all(promises)
    .then(function(res) {
      workService.doSomething(res[0].data, res[1].data);
      console.log("response:", res);
      // I want to return a string, or object, back to a variable in my controller
      //return statusService.getStatusMessage(res[0]);
    }, function(err) {
      console.log("error:", err);
      //return statusService.getStatusMessage(err);
    }
  );      
};

function queryApi(url) {
  return $http.get(url);
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think you need to work with `$q` promises: (1) initialise `deferred = $q.defer();` , (2) gather results `$q.all(promises).then((res) => { deferred.resolve(res); });` , (3) return a promise `return deferred.promise;`, then your controller can get result with: `myService.doSomeWork(...).then((res) => { var statusMessage = res; })`

Comment: This worked, thank you. Could you write out an answer so that I can award it to you?

Comment: Using `$q.deferred` with promise-based APIs is probematic. For more infromation, see [Is this a “Deferred Antipattern”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30750207/is-this-a-deferred-antipattern).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In AngularJS, asynchronous services should [return](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return) a promise. To transform promise data in a service, be sure to [return](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return) the transformed data to the `.then` method handler function:

```
factory.doSomeWork = function() {        
  var promises = [
    queryApi("firstApiCall"), 
    queryApi("secondApiCall")
  ];

   ̲r̲e̲t̲u̲r̲n̲ $q.all(promises)
    .then(function successHandler(res) {
      workService.doSomething(res[0].data, res[1].data);
      console.log("response:", res);
      // I want to return a string, or object, back to a variable in my controller
       ̲r̲e̲t̲u̲r̲n̲ transformedData;
    }, function rejectionHandler(err) {
      console.log("error:", err);
       ̶/̶/̶r̶e̶t̶u̶r̶n̶ ̶s̶t̶a̶t̶u̶s̶S̶e̶r̶v̶i̶c̶e̶.̶g̶e̶t̶S̶t̶a̶t̶u̶s̶M̶e̶s̶s̶a̶g̶e̶(̶e̶r̶r̶)̶;̶
       ̲t̲h̲r̲o̲w̲ statusService.getStatusMessage(err);
    }
  );      
};
```

It is important to use a [throw statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/throw) in rejection handlers. Otherwise the rejected promise will be **converted** to a successful promise.

In the controller:

```
function doWork() {
  var promise = myService.doSomeWork();

  promise.then(function(transformedData) {
      console.log(transformedData);
  }).catch(function(err) {
      console.log(err);
  });

  // what I'm going for:
  // var statusMessage = myService.doSomeWork(sharedDataService.onThisThing);
}
```

For more information, see [You're Missing the Point of Promises](https://blog.domenic.me/youre-missing-the-point-of-promises/).

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for and it works perfectly. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a callback from the service like

```
  factory.doSomeWork = function(callback) {        
 var promises = [
   queryApi("firstApiCall"), 
   queryApi("secondApiCall")
];

 $q.all(promises)
   .then(function(res) {
  //do a callback

  callback(res)

   }, function(err) {
       console.log("error:", err);

   }
  );      
};
```

and in your controller  you can receive the result

```
  function doWork() {
  myService.doSomeWork(function(result){
 //handle the result
});
```

}

Comment: Using a callback like that is problematic. If any of the promise have an error the callback will never be called. For more information, see [Why are Callbacks from Promise `.then` Methods an Anti-Pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35660881/why-are-callbacks-from-promise-then-methods-an-anti-pattern).

Comment: @georgeawg yeah make sense !