# AngularJS - Factory from Controller - not getting value from $http.get

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-controller, angularjs-factory, angularjs-http

I have a newbie question here.

I am coding a factory in angularJS. With it I want to have a list of users, and also a method to fill it.

So this is my code ...

The factory

```
app.factory("usuariosFactory", function ($http) {


    var f = {};

    f.users = [];

    f.getUsers = function (callback) {
        var token = window.localStorage.getItem("_token");


        $http.get("http://localhost:8000/api/user/list?token=" + token).then(function (response) {
            f.users = response.data.users;

            /* the console.log outputs OK with the users from the server */
            console.log(f.users);
        });
    }; 

    return f;
});
```

The controller

```
app.controller("usuariosController", function ($scope, usuariosFactory) {
    var scope = this;

    /* link users from factory to controllerś scope .. NOT WORKING */
    usuariosFactory.getUsers();

    scope.usuarios = usuariosFactory.users;
});
```

I am hitting my head to the desk right now. I dont understand how to achieve this.

Comment: See [Why are Callbacks from Promise `.then` Methods an Anti-Pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35660881/why-are-callbacks-from-promise-then-methods-an-anti-pattern).

Comment: See also [You're Missing the Point of Promises](https://blog.domenic.me/youre-missing-the-point-of-promises/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just `return` the `promise` from the `factory` to `controller`

Then in `controller`, you should `subscribe` to that `promise` and assign data to your `scope variable`

**Factory:**

```
app.factory("usuariosFactory", function ($http) {
    var f = {};
    f.users = [];
    f.getUsers = function (callback) {
        var token = window.localStorage.getItem("_token");
        return $http.get("http://localhost:8000/api/user/list?token=" + token);
    };
    return f;
});
```

**Controller:**

```
app.controller("usuariosController", function ($scope, usuariosFactory) {
    var scope = this;
    usuariosFactory.getUsers().then(function (response) {
        scope.usuarios = response.data;
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

The `usuariosFactory.getUsers` is an asynchronous function, due to `$http.get` inside. So, to have your data, you have to use the callback function that you've already put in the `getUsers`. The code should be like:

```
usuariosFactory.getUsers(function () {
    scope.usuarios = usuariosFactory.users;
});
```

and after the `f.users = response.data.users;` you have to call the callback function. Like this:

```
f.getUsers = function (callback) {
    var token = window.localStorage.getItem("_token");
    $http.get("http://localhost:8000/api/user/list?token=" + token).then(function (response) {
        f.users = response.data.users;
        callback();
    });
};
```

That way you will handle ansynchronous functions with a callback funtion. Another way to do this is with promises, in that way, your code should be like this:

The factory

```
app.factory("usuariosFactory", function ($http, $q) {
    var f = {};
    f.users = [];

    f.getUsers = function (callback) {
        var token = window.localStorage.getItem("_token");
        var deferred = $q.defer(); // Creates the object that handles the promise
        $http.get("http://localhost:8000/api/user/list?token=" + token)
            .then(function (response) {
                f.users = response.data.users;
                deferred.resolve('You can pass data!'); // Informs that the asynchronous operation have finished
            });
        return deferred.promise; // Returns a promise that something will happen later
    };

    return f;
});
```

The controller

```
app.controller("usuariosController", function ($scope, usuariosFactory) {
    var scope = this;

    // Now you can use your function just like you use $http
    // This way, you know that watever should happen in getUsers, will be avaible in the function
    usuariosFactory.getUsers()
        .then(function (data) {
            console.log(data) // Print 'You can pass data!'
            scope.usuarios = usuariosFactory.users; 
        });
});
```

Comment: Classic [deferred antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it) - I recommend avoiding this type of factory and returning the promise directly instead.

Comment: @Lex, you mean returning http.get() instead?

Comment: I mean returning the promise that is created as a result of calling `$http.get()`. Read the answer at the link - dealing with promises is a pretty integral part of Angular and you should understand the implications of using them.

Comment: See [Why are Callbacks from Promise `.then` Methods an Anti-Pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35660881/why-are-callbacks-from-promise-then-methods-an-anti-pattern).

Comment: to everyone of you, thanks very much, this post really took me through a lot of reading. Now at least I know how I should deal with promises in the proper way according to theory.

Comment: I will not mark this answer as correct just because there is another one that exactly handles the pattern accepted by the theory. but this answer works ... it is just not well embarecd to the theory behind promises