# AngularJS two http get in one controller make problems

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise, angular-http, ng-controller

i have two http GET in one controller and sometimes it works and two of them are working. sometime only one http Get is work. and sometimes none of them is shown.
any suggestions?

```
 }).controller("nextSidorAdminCtrl", 
 function($scope,$rootScope,$http,$location,$state) {
   $http.get("/ShiftWeb/rest/admin/getallsettingtime")
  .then(function(response) {
    $scope.settingtimes = response.data;
 });    
 $http.get("/ShiftWeb/rest/admin/nextsidor")
    .then(function(response) {
    $scope.nextsidor = response.data;
 });
```

Image:

https://prnt.sc/k5ewd6

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chain the two $http.get operations:

```
}).controller("nextSidorAdminCtrl", 
   function($scope,$rootScope,$http,$location,$state) {
       $http.get("/ShiftWeb/rest/admin/getallsettingtime")
       .then(function(response) {
           $scope.settingtimes = response.data;
           return $http.get("/ShiftWeb/rest/admin/nextsidor")
       })    
       .then(function(response) {
           $scope.nextsidor = response.data;
       });
```

Because calling the `.then` method of a promise returns a new derived promise, it is easily possible to create a chain of promises. It is possible to create chains of any length and since a promise can be resolved with another promise (which will defer its resolution further), it is possible to pause/defer resolution of the promises at any point in the chain.

For more information, see [AngularJS $q Service API Reference - chaining promises](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)

Comment: hey man can you answer me for another question? how to i use to veryify a delete function. i mean how to alert the client and ask him if he sure or not to delete the Worker to example. and only if he press Yes. it will delete him? how do i do that in angular

Comment: do you have other solution to promise not to delete( example: worker ) mistakely? and how do i use that the function will be called on the OK press

Answer (score -1):

**The best way to solve this problem is to use [async](https://github.com/caolan/async/blob/v1.5.2/README.md)**

In my openion, The problem in Mr. georgeawg's answer is, if **`$http.get("/ShiftWeb/rest/admin/getallsettingtime")`** will return `success` then **`$http.get("/ShiftWeb/rest/admin/nextsidor")`** will be called, **Otherwise It will not be called.**

And as I can see in the question both are independent.

So you need to follow the best way which is used async or something like that.

**So your code will be :**

```
 var getAllAettingTime = function(cb) {
      $http.get("/ShiftWeb/rest/admin/getallsettingtime")
      .then(function(response) {
          if(response.data){
                   $scope.settingtimes = response.data;
                    return cb(null,'OK');
          }else{
                    return cb(null,'ERROR');
       })
}

 var nextSidor= function(cb) {
   $http.get("/ShiftWeb/rest/admin/nextsidor")
   .then(function(response) {
          if(response.data){
                   $scope.nextsidor = response.data;
                    return cb(null,'OK');
          }else{
                    return cb(null,'ERROR');
       })
}

async.series([ getAllAettingTime, nextSidor], function(err, result) {
  if (err){
             /* Do what you want if err comes */
  } else {
              /* Do what you want if both HTTP come with success */
   }
});
```

In the above **`async.series()`** both HTTP will be called without any dependency on each other.

For better understanding, you need study about [async npm module](https://github.com/caolan/async/blob/v1.5.2/README.md) and have to install in your app.

Comment: i already used what  Mr. georgeawg's  said and it works great! and its really a short solution. But i have another question if u can help me pls: how to i use to veryify a delete function. i mean how to alert the client and ask him if he sure or not to delete the Worker to example. and only if he press Yes. it will delete him? how do i do that in angular

Comment: See [Why are Callbacks from Promise `.then` Methods an Anti-Pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35660881/why-are-callbacks-from-promise-then-methods-an-anti-pattern).