# AngularJS $scope.Itemlist undefined

Tags: angularjs

Good day I am trying to read data from the database but its not working properly i need to refresh twice to load the data. And if the data was not load properly the scope.item list stated not define. Thanks

```
$scope.ItemList = [];
$http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'json/Item.php',
}).success(function (result) {
    $scope.ItemList = result;
});

$http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'json/ItemOrder.php?ID=' + $scope.DeliveryID,
}).success(function (result) {

    $scope.result = result;


    angular.forEach($scope.result, function (value, key) {

        var currentIndex = 0;
        var index = 0;
        var ItemID = value.ItemID;

        angular.forEach($scope.ItemList, function (value, key) {
            if (value.ItemID == ItemID) {
                currentIndex = index;
            }
            index++;
        });

        $scope.currentItemId = $scope.ItemList[currentIndex];
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you console.log on $scope.ItemList = result to see what is the result that you get ?

Comment: i get result from the database and pass data to $scope.ItemList but as i observed, i have 300+ records in the database  somehow that the $http bypass the process and then proceed to the foreach i think
thanks so much

Comment: Actually it happens because your `ItemOrder.php` may return result earlier than `Item.php`.

Comment: though even if it happens you are defining $scope.ItemList  = []; on top before http calls. So undefined doesn't make sense. Unless your `Item.php` returns nothing and `$scope.ItemList = result` is basically setting `$scope.ItemList = undefined // result is undefined.`

Comment: i try your suggestion and i return undefined $scope.ItemList but when i check the console it display the data from the database.

Comment: I suggest to queue your both async calls with $q and once you have all results check whether your first request actually delivers an expected (ot at least empty) array.

Comment: can you give me the link on how to queue ? thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS two http get in one controller make problems](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51296209/5535245).

Answer (score 0):

Chain the two $http.get requests:

```
$scope.ItemList = [];
$http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'json/Item.php',
}).then(function (response) {
    var result = response.data;
    $scope.ItemList = result;
    return $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'json/ItemOrder.php?ID=' + $scope.DeliveryID,
    });
}).then(function (response) {
    var result = response.data;
    $scope.result = result;

    //code that uses $scope.ItemList
});
```

Because calling the `.then` method of a promise returns a new derived promise, it is easily possible to create a chain of promises. It is possible to create chains of any length and since a promise can be resolved with another promise (which will defer its resolution further), it is possible to pause/defer resolution of the promises at any point in the chain.

For more information, see [AngularJS $q Service API Reference - chaining promises](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)