# AngularJS build object from three different api calls

Tags: json, angularjs, api, jenkins

i want to build a jenkins dashboard with angularJS. I need or want (don't know if the idea is good) combine the data I received from three different API calls to build an object out of it to use it as ng-repeat in the html file.

The data structure should look like:

**JSON object**

```
{
  "Job1": {
    "branchname1": {
      "stagename1": {
        "stage_status": "SUCCESS"
      },
      "stagename2": {
        "stage_status": "FAILED"
      }
    }
  },
  "Job2": {
    "branchname1": {
      "stagename1": {
        "stage_status": "SUCCESS"
      },
      "stagename2": {
        "stage_status": "FAILED"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**AngularJS code**

```
angular.module('App')
  .controller('IndexCtrl', function($scope, $route, $routeParams, $rootScope, $http, $location, $log, $q, moment, $filter) {

    $scope.api = 'http://127.0.0.1:8080';
    $scope.customer = '';
    $scope.jobs = [];

    function getJobs(customer, callback) {
      $scope.customer = customer;
      $http.get($scope.api + '/job/' + customer + '/api/json?tree=jobs[name]').then(function(response) {
        angular.forEach(response.data.jobs, function(value, index) {
          $scope.jobs.push(value.name);
        });
        callback(response);
      },
      function(error) {
        alert("Could not fetch jobs from " + $scope.api);
      });
    }

    function getData(resp) {
      requests = [];
      angular.forEach(resp.data.jobs, function(value) {
        requests.push($http.get($scope.api + '/job/' + $scope.customer + '/job/' + value.name + '/api/json'));
         console.log(value.name); // OUTPUT: Job1 Job2
      });

      $q.all(requests).then(function(result) {
        angular.forEach(result, function(value) {
          angular.forEach(value.data.jobs, function(index) {

            if(index.name.match( /(hotfix|release|master)/ )) {

              console.log(index.name); // OUTPUT: branchname1 branchname2
              $http.get($scope.api + '/job/' + $scope.customer + '/job/' + value.data.name + '/job/' + index.name + '/wfapi/runs').then(function(response) {

                angular.forEach(response.data[0].stages, function(index) {
                  console.log(index.name); // OUTPUT: stagename1 stagename2
                  console.log(index.status); // OUTPUT: SUCCESS FAILED
                });
              });
            }
          });
        });
      });
    }
    getJobs("project1", getData);
  })
```

Is it possible to create an object out of the outputs shown in console.log?
If not what is the best way to achieve a result like this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To build objects from multiple API calls, use the AngularJS [`$q.all`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#all) method. Unlike ES6 JavaScript [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all), AngularJS `$q.all` accepts a hash object of promises.

First, re-factor the `getJobs` function to return a promise:

```
function getJobs(customer) {
    var url = $scope.api + '/job/' + customer + '/api/json?tree=jobs[name]';
    var promise = $http.get(url);
    var newPromise = promise.then(function(response) {
        var jobs = [];
        angular.forEach(response.data.jobs, function(value, index) {
            jobs.push(value.name);
        });
        return jobs;
    },function(error) {
        alert("Could not fetch jobs from " + $scope.api);
        throw error;
    });
    return newPromise;
}
```

Then use that function to create a hash object to resolve with `$q.all`:

```
var dataPromise = getJobs("project1").then(function (jobs) {
    var dataPromiseObj = {};
    angular.forEach(jobs, function (job) {
        dataPromiseObj[job] =  getDataForJob(job);
    });
    return $q.all(dataPromiseObj);
});

dataPromise.then(function(dataObj) {
    console.log(dataObj);
});
```

The `.then` method *returns a new promise* which is resolved or rejected via the return value of the `successCallback`, `errorCallback` (unless that value is a promise, in which case it is resolved with the value which is resolved in that promise using [promise chaining](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/#toc-promises-queues)).

For more information, see

- [AngularJS $q Service API Reference - The Promise API](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#the-promise-api)
- [Why are Callbacks from Promise `.then` Methods an Anti-Pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35660881/why-are-callbacks-from-promise-then-methods-an-anti-pattern)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick feedback. The first function is working perfectly! I did the same with the second one and get those returns {CORS: Array(3), MORS: Array(3)} CORS: Array(3) 0: "hotfix" 1: "master" 2: "release" MORS: Array(3) 0: "hotfix" 1: "master" 2: "release" How is it possible to achieve a structure like Job1": { "branchname1": { "stagename1": { "stage_status": "SUCCESS" }, Should i create a function for each api call or should I leave the rest all in one?