# AngularJS: Sharing a function between controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-service

I've read in other SO answers that code that doesn't manipulate the view should be accessed via `services`. However, I have a function that I want to share over several Angular controllers, which accesses both `$scope`, `$rootScope` and `$location`:

```
    $scope.selectBatch = function (id) {
        if (!id) {
            $scope.batchSelected = false;
            $rootScope.job = false;
            $scope.data = allData;
            $location.path('/', false);
        } else {
            $scope.batchSelected = id;
            $rootScope.job = {'BatchId': id};
            var arr = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < allData.length; i++) {

                if (String(allData[i].BatchId) === String(id)) {
                    arr.push(allData[i]);
                }
            }

            $scope.data = arr;
            $rootScope.go(id, 'batch');
        }
    };
```

Ideally, in each controller I'd like to do something like:

```
 $scope.selectBatch = services.selectBatch($scope, $rootscope, $location);
```

to load in this function from a service, although this feels "non-angular".

What's the "Angular" / MVC way of injecting this sort of function into multiple controllers?

Comment: How do the controllers differ? Could you just re-use the one controller?

Comment: No, the controllers are very different in terms of the data they bring in and how it's handled. There are one or two functions like this that are shared across all controllers though.

Comment: Doesn't really make sense to modify $scope primitives before doing a redirect. Should never need to pass `$scope` into service/factory either

Comment: This is what angular services were made for. So you could share data among controllers. You should keep that function in a service and inject that service into everyone of the controllers.

Comment: @charlietfl I get what you mean, although that's not a redirect - it's actually an extension of `$location.path()` to allow a rewrite of the URL without refreshing the page / changing controller. A little hackier than I like but in the context of the app it makes sense.

Comment: @ggderas So are you saying that what I've done in the example at the bottom is the correct way to do it? (i.e. passing `$scope`, `$rootScope` and `$location` to the service)

Comment: @Jascination yes. Because you want to get access of the controllers from within a service. Or am I wrong? Although the flow proposed by Angular MVC is the other way around. Share data among controllers using services.

Comment: @Jascination but so you're not sending the $scope and $rootScope parameters?

Comment: @ggderas I wrote an answer below, feel free to edit / add your own if there's a better way to do it :)

Answer (score 0):

From the comments on this question it appears the correct answer is to do it like this:

**1. Create a service that returns a function**

```
angular.module('myApp.services', []).service('shared', ['$location', function ($location) {

   this.selectBatch = function($rootScope, $scope){
      return function(id){
         // Do stuff with $location, id, $rootScope and $scope here
      }
   }

}]);
```

**2. Inject the service and associated functions into your controllers**

```
.controller('myCtrl', ['shared', '$scope', '$rootScope'
    function (shared, $scope, $rootScope) {

        $scope.selectBatch = shared.selectBatch($rootScope, $scope);

}]);
```

You can then call this function using `$scope.selectBatch(id)` and it works as expected.

Happy to consider other answers if there are "better" ways to achieve this.

Comment: Why inject `$rootScope` into every controller when you can simply inject it once in service?

Answer (score 0):

> Angular services are substitutable objects that are wired together using dependency injection (DI). You can use services to organize and share code across your app.

***You can use services to organize and share code across your app***

Be aware that sending $scope as parameter to a service is not a good idea. Instead you could send the parameters the function needs in order to process something. This way your service could be more reusable.

Check this SO Question: [Injecting $scope into an angular service function()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22898927/injecting-scope-into-an-angular-service-function)

Ideally you could write a shared service like this:

```
app.factory('sharedService', ['$location', function($location)
{
    var sharedService = {};

    sharedService.selectBatch  = function(batchSelected, job, data, id)
    {
        //Do something with batchSelected, job, data, id parameters
    };

    return sharedService;
}]);
```

Then all your controllers could look like this

```
app.controller('myCtrl', ['sharedService', function(sharedService)
{

    $scope.batchSelected;
    $scope.job;
    $scope.data;
    $scope.id;

    $scope.selectBatch = sharedService.selectBatch($scope.batchSelected, $scope.job, $scope.data, $scope.id);
}]);
```

**NOTE**

You don't have to send the $location parameter either, since you could inject it in your shared service.