# AngularJS: $scope is not defined?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've started learning Angular JS ,I keep getting '$scope is not defined' console errors for this controller code in AngularJS:
any idea ?

**Service :signup.js**

```
    'use strict';

angular.module('crud')
  .service('Signup',function () {

         var data={
        email:$scope.email,password:$scope.password,confirmPassword:$scope.confirmPassword  
    }
    //console.log(data);
    $sails.post("/api/user",data)
      .success(function (data, status, headers, jwr) {
            $scope.users=data;


        //$scope.user=data;
      })
      .error(function (data, status, headers, jwr) {

       console.log(data);
       //console.log(headers);
        alert('Houston, we got a problem!');
      });       



  });
```

**Signupcontroller.js**

```
 'use strict';

    angular.module('crud')
      .controller('SignupCtrl', function ($scope,Signup) {


        // Using .success() and .error()


    });
```

Comment: $scope only available in controller.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Intro

Have a look at the following answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22899880/1688441

You should not be trying to directly use `$scope` from a service since it isn't available. The `$scope` of your controller will contain some variables/objects that you could then pass to your service through calls.

The answer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/22899880 shows a correct way of implementing what you wish to do and is nearly the structure you essentially  need (with different names).

Obviously you will need to make changes such as, rewriting his save method method to perform the HTTP post and contact the server with a response to the login request. Also since http requests are asynchronous it may be better to use a `resource`. See: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource

### Quick Rough Example

```
angular.module('crud').service('SignupService', ['$http', function ($http) {
    var path = '/api/user';

    var loginHttpPost = function (data) {
        return $http.post(path,data);   //Return the promise, or instead of a service make a resource, see: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource      
    };  
}])

angular.module('crud').controller('SignupCtrl', function ($scope,SignupService) {

        $scope.login = function () {
           var data={email:$scope.email,password:$scope.password,confirmPassword:$scope.confirmPassword}; 

           //HTTP calls are asynchronous. Maybe better to use resource. Must use promise.

           SignupService.loginHttpPost(data).success(function (data) {
                //Do whatever is needed
                $scope.loginResults = //assign result
           }).error(function (data) {
                //Do whatever is needed
                $scope.loginResults = //assign result
           });  
        };
    }
]);
```

Comment: nice explanation. But i think `$sails.post("/api/user",data)` is not outside the service, it is inside. Am i wrong?

Comment: @maythesource.com i'm using .service  not factory is this the same ?

Comment: @letseasy it's not the exact same as services are singletons and factories return objects. I changed the rough code to a service: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13762228/confused-about-service-vs-factory

Comment: @maythesource.com one question : I dont undestand this line return $http.post(path,data);    what do u mean about promise ?

Comment: post of $http returns an httpPromise once tha result comes back. See: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#post . Have a good read of that doc and note most calls are asynchronous meaning the http call is initiated on another thread and your remaining code is executed. Only the callback functions assigned to the promise with success or error are executed after the http request.

Answer (score 0):

You are not correctly injecting `$scope` and the service `Signup`. 
Also `$scope` is only available in controller. So you need to pass it to service from controller.

Below is the right way of doing it.

```
 'use strict';

  angular.module('crud')
  .controller('SignupCtrl',['$scope','Signup', function ($scope,Signup) {


  }]);
```

Comment: While this is the minification safe way to inject dependencies, his current method does work without minification. The problem is with his `Signup` service.