# Angular JS services not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

so i am kinda new to angularjs and is facing a little difficulty with services. so i was working on an angularjs TO DO app and with services and can not get it working.
This is my controller

```
.controller("myController", ['$scope','toDoService', function($scope,toDoService){

    var lists = toDoService.getLists();
    $scope.lists = lists;

    $scope.add = function(){
      // WHAT TO PUT HERE????

    }
```

and this is my service

```
 .service('toDoService', function(){
      this.getLists =function(){
          var list = [
              {"name" : "abebe" ,"done":false, id: Date.now()}
          ];
          return list;
      }


      this.add = function(){
         $scope.lists.push({'name':$scope.nameSpace,'done':false, id: Date.now()});
      $scope.nameSpace = '';
         return this;
      }

  });
```

THANK YOU IN ADVANCE

Comment: do you have any error ?

Comment: nop, there are no errors in my console

Answer (score 2):

You can't use $scope inside a service like this.

See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22899880/3619813

Answer (score 1):

You can not use $scope inside service. Check the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/8187/) to understand how it should work.

```
myApp.service('toDoService', function(){
            this.details = {
        lists: [
              {"name" : "abebe" ,"done":false, id: Date.now()}
          ]
      }
      this.getLists =function(){
          var list = [
              {"name" : "abebe" ,"done":false, id: Date.now()}
          ];
          return list;
      }
      this.addList = function(item) {
        this.details.lists.push(item)
      }
  });

myApp.controller("myController", ['$scope','toDoService',       
    function($scope,toDoService){
    $scope.lists = function() { return toDoService.details.lists };
    $scope.add = function(){
      // WHAT TO PUT HERE????
      var newListItem = {"name" : "abebe" ,"done":false, id: Date.now()}
      toDoService.addList(newListItem)
    }
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is the complete code.

```
.controller("myController", ['$scope','toDoService', function($scope,toDoService){

var lists = toDoService.getLists();
$scope.lists = lists;

$scope.add = function(){
    toDoService.add($scope.lists);

}
```

Your service will look like below.

```
.service('toDoService', function(){

    this.lists = [];

    this.getLists =function(){
        var list = [
            {"name" : "abebe" ,"done":false, id: Date.now()}
        ];
        return list;
    }


    this.add = function(data){
        lists.push(data);
        return lists;
    }

});
```