# Using AngularJS Service in Controller

Tags: angularjs, service, controllers

Service:

```
app.service('myService', ['$scope', '$timeout', function($scope, $timeout){
   return {
      fn: function(messageTitle, messageContent) {
        $timeout(function() {
            $scope.fadeMessageSuccess = true;
        }, 3000);
      }
   }
}]);
```

Controller:

```
app.controller("AccountCtrl", ["$scope", "Auth", "$timeout", "myService",
  function($scope, Auth, $timeout, myService) {
    myService.fn();
    $scope.createUser = function() {
      $scope.message = null;
      $scope.error = null;

      // Create a new user
      Auth.$createUserWithEmailAndPassword($scope.accountEmailAddress, $scope.accountPassword)
        .then(function(firebaseUser) {
          $scope.message = "User created with uid: " + firebaseUser.uid;
          console.log($scope.message);
        }).catch(function(error) {
          $scope.error = error;
          console.log($scope.error);
        });
    };
  }
]);
```

I'm trying to create a service so that I can use a function in multiple controllers but I'm have trouble getting this first one working.  This is the error message I'm getting in console:

```
angular.js:13550Error: [$injector:unpr]
```

Comment: Using the non-minified angularjs file should give you a more detailed error message.

Comment: See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22898927/injecting-scope-into-an-angular-service-function). Injecting `$scope` into a service doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Just an observation: doesn't look like you're passing anything to the function when you're calling it.  And not sure if you're wanting to add any more functionality to the service, but I think you can return the function directly and just call "myService(title, content);".  But I don't think those issues would cause what you're encountering.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you were trying to return an object (a la the `.factory()` function) when you were trying to use `.service()`. [Here is a dead simple explanation for .factory, .service, and .provider](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26924234/4020932).

As pointed out by user2341963, injecting `$scope` into a service doesn't make much sense.

Also, are you sure all of your dependencies are defined and available to Angular?

[Here is an example Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/htjtvWNdBCm39NatofDN?p=preview) of using a service in a controller.