# Unable to add $scope to service in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, browserify, angular-services, grunt-browserify

The code for my `angular service` is

```
// service/user.js
const env = require('../environment');

module.exports = function ($scope) {
    this.is_authenticated = false;
};
```

and i am initialising the service using

```
// service/index.js
const angular = require('angular');

var app = angular.module('application');
app.service('auth',require('./user'));
```

The angular app definition is

```
// app.js
const angular = require('angular');

var app = angular.module('application',[]);

require('./config');
require('./service');
```

The error i am getting is

> Unknown provider: $scopeProvider <- $scope <- auth

The project is being built using `browserify` where am i going wrong with this ?

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22898927/injecting-scope-into-an-angular-service-function).

Comment: @SinDeus now i know... thanks a lot :)